# Reg: Substr and column length

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a small issue. I have a table with the below description.

```
SQL> desc ERROR
  Name                                      Null?    Type
  ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
  DPDATE_TIME                               NOT NULL DATE
  ERR_MSG                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(132)
  CODE1                                              VARCHAR2(50)
```

Now for the above table when i select the CODE1 as given below

```
SELECT substr(code1, 1,length(code1)) as name From ERROR where code1='xxxxAXP'

NAME
--------------------------------------------------
xxxxAXP
xxxxAXP
```

It picks the length of that column and then displays it. I mean instead of showing only 7 character, it is showing 50 character with spaces.

But if i do

```
SELECT substr(code1, 1,7) as name From ERROR where code1='xxxxAXP'

NAME
-------
xxxxAXP
xxxxAXP
```

Then it works perfectly. I cannot use the below query because the length of each code can be different and hard coding it to 7 is bad. IS there any generic way to achieve this ? Thank you.

Comment: `substr(code1,1,length(code1))` is by definition the same as `code1`, and unless I'm missing something your 'wrong' and 'right' results are the same, so it's not clear what output you need.

Comment: _" it is showing 50 character with spaces."_ No, that's just column length in the output in SQL*Plus, strings are still the same 7 characters.

Comment: Oh I think I see, it's the SQL\*Plus formatting. `substr(code1,1,7)` returns a 7-character column from the database, and so SQL\*Plus can display it as 7 characters (similar to `column code1 format a7`). But you want it to adjust the display dynamically to fit the longest value stored in the column at the time of the query. For that you will need to write your own query to find out what it is. Obviously SQL\*Plus doesn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like column length - displayed in SQL*Plus - is 50 characters long.

But, is column's length really that? This results in what you claim to be wrong:

```
SELECT substr(code1, 1,length(code1)) as name From ERROR where code1='xxxxAXP'
```

What is result of

```
SELECT LENGTH(substr(code1, 1,length(code1))) as name From ERROR where code1='xxxxAXP'
       ------                               -
```

Because, if SQL*Plus is bothering you, format column as you want it using

```
col name format a5
```

---

Demo on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> desc emp
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                           DATE
 SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                               NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)

SQL> select substr(ename, 1, length(ename)) as name from emp where rownum = 1;

NAME
----------
SMITH

SQL> select substr(ename, 1, 5) as name from emp where rownum = 1;

NAME
-----
SMITH

SQL> col name format a5
SQL> select substr(ename, 1, length(ename)) as name from emp where rownum = 1;

NAME
-----
SMITH

SQL>
```

Comment: Sql*plus just gets column definition of cursor from Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Sqlplus analyzes column definition of cursor which built at parse, not runtime. So it doesn't know that you really have just 7 chars. Sqlcl analyzes also output, so try sqlcl instead.

Oracle returns columns definitions, not SQL*Plus:

```
create table ERROR(
  DPDATE_TIME DATE,
  ERR_MSG     VARCHAR2(132),
  CODE1       VARCHAR2(50 byte)
);
insert into error(code1) values('xxxxAXP');
commit
/
Declare
     SQL_stmt  varchar2(2000) := 'select substr(code1, 1,length(code1)) as name from error';
     ColCount  number:=0;
     DestTab   dbms_sql.desc_tab;
     CursorId  integer;
begin
   CursorId:= dbms_sql.open_cursor;
   dbms_sql.parse(CursorId,SQL_stmt,dbms_sql.native);
   dbms_sql.describe_columns(CursorId,ColCount,DestTab);
 
   for i in 1 .. ColCount loop
    dbms_output.put_line('ColumnType:    ' || DestTab(i).col_type);
    dbms_output.put_line('Maximum Length: ' || DestTab(i).col_max_len);
    dbms_output.put_line('ColumnName:    ' || DestTab(i).col_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('Name Length:   ' || DestTab(i).col_name_len);
    dbms_output.put_line('Scale:         ' || DestTab(i).col_scale);
    dbms_output.put_line('Precision:     ' || DestTab(i).col_precision);
    dbms_output.put_line('Charsetid:     ' || DestTab(i).col_Charsetid);
    dbms_output.put_line('Charset Form:  ' || DestTab(i).col_charsetform);
    if (DestTab(i).col_null_ok) then
       dbms_output.put_line('IsNull:Y');
    else
       dbms_output.put_line('IsNull:N');
    end if;
    dbms_output.new_line;
   end loop;
   dbms_sql.close_cursor(CursorId);
   exception
   when others then dbms_sql.close_cursor(CursorId);
     raise;
end;
/
```

Comment: I cannot hardcode the substr(code1,1,7) as mentioned in the question. So what option can i use to dynamically subst the column value at runtime?

Comment: @VimalBhaskar use modern Oracle SQLCl or SQLDeveloper instead of SQL*Plus: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic why sql*plus shows 50 length with space in case of `length()` and 7 size in case of constant number 7 in `substr`:

Sql*plus do not know how long each record will be in case of `length()` so it shows the 50 characters with space which is equal to column's actual size.

In case of 7 in `substr`, it knows that each result will be 7 character long or smaller, so it shows size with 7 characters only.

Comment: Sql*plus just gets column definition of cursor from Oracle

Comment: so it should be "<s>Sql*plus</s> Oracle do not know how long each record will be in case of length() so it shows the 50 characters with space which is equal to column's actual size."

Comment: Yes, That is what I have mentioned in the answer.